# Does v$sql_monitor show all queries?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I cannot see all queries with `v$sql_monitor` or `gv$sql_monitor`.  I can see some queries, none of which have `/*+ MONITOR */`.  I have tested a query with MONITOR and it still did not show.  I thought it might just be a big explain problem, so I adjusted my session with:

```
ALTER SESSION SET "_SQLMON_MAX_PLAN"=4020;
ALTER SESSION SET "_SQLMON_MAX_PLANLINES"=4000;

select first_refresh_time, last_refresh_time, 
status, sql_text 
from v$sql_monitor 
order by last_refresh_time desc;
```

, but it didn't help.  What I am trying to do is see query submitted via an application.  The query works, so I know it is hitting the database.  I simply cannot see the query in Oracle.

What am I doing wrong?  I am using SQL Developer if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle explains the [V$SQL_MONITOR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3048.htm#REFRN30479) view in its official documentation.

Looks like it only keeps the record there for a minute or two, or until it needs the space to show the other queries.

> **Disclaimer**
>   The original answer was posted as a comment by [@MguerraTorres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/99943/mguerratorres)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Monitoring will be triggered if one of the following conditions is present:

- query is taking more than 5 seconds of CPU time
  or
- query is taking more than 5 seconds waiting on I/O
  or
- query is running in parallel
  or
- `/*+ MONITOR */` hint was present in the query

In other words, if your query is a very fast one, doesn't run in parallel and doesn't have MONITOR hint, it won't be monitored.